# Проверка касания, obj-c. cocos2d

Tags: objective-c

День добрый,

Начинаю разбираться в cocos2d, Никак не могу найти информацию по моему вопросу

На экране есть объект(имя myButton), как узнать - что пользователь нажал на него?

Создаю функцию, а что дальше? я привык к hitTest, а какая здесь философия?

```
-(void) ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
```

Comment: А что мешает при создании кнопки указать коллбек, который будет вызываться при тапе?

Comment: У меня не кнопка - а просто спрайт. А есть такая возможность ? (я имею в виду не CCMenu)

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте, лежит ли точка касания внутри этого объекта:

```
 CGRectContainsPoint (CGRect rect, CGPoint point)`
```

Comment: Разобрался! Спасибо!